# share a card from bot to another person in ms team

Tags: chatbot, microsoft-teams, botframework

Ex:- Bot send me a card and I want to share that card with another person in ms team

Is it possible in bot framework?

Comment: Yes you can send message to other person when you click on button,
On click of button you can get all members in the channel by using Get paged members method and send message to your manager.You can refer the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot/Bots/TeamsConversationBot.cs#L175).

Comment: @VaraPrasad-MSFT I tried this sample but I am not getting members, is it possible to get all members of my organisation and then I pick the name whom I want to share a card.

Comment: If you want to get the member details, the member should be part of a team.If you want to get all members in your organization you can achieve this by using [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) .